# Volkswagen rear wiper motor compatibility

Tags: vw, golf, windshield-wipers, motors

Is the rear wiper motor OEM number **6x0 955 711 d** (taken from VW Polo 2002) compatible with Golf MkIV (current motor has OEM number **1j6 955 711 b**?

I do not own this kind of vehicle so I cannot try it myself

Comment: what vehicle did it come off?

Comment: VW Polo 2002. Updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid not.. that wiper motor is shared with the Lupo (1999-2003) but not the Golf.

Incidentally the part number you have for the Golf's wiper motor seems to be wrong.. 1J6955711**C** is what I have?

Here's a list of parts that should fit:

```
title       number        manufacturer
Wiper Motor 0390201592    BOSCH
Wiper Motor 064039002010  MAGNETI MARELLI
Wiper Motor 1008990082    MEYLE
Wiper Motor 111300        TOPRAN
Wiper Motor 14-WM-106     ITN
Wiper Motor 30543         FEBI BILSTEIN
Wiper Motor 30930543      SWAG
Wiper Motor 3095507111J6G AUTOMEGA
Wiper Motor 404425        VALEO
Wiper Motor 404886        VALEO
Wiper Motor 460003        ERA
Wiper Motor 51658         A.I.C. Competition
Wiper Motor 7223,755,1    BINDER
Wiper Motor 800019        ALANKO
Wiper Motor 90185         MAPCO
Wiper Motor 955296004ALT  JP GROUP
Wiper Motor 99.0387       LAUBER
Wiper Motor CWM15326AS    CASCO
Wiper Motor CWM15326GS    CASCO
Wiper Motor V10-07-0005   VEMO
Wiper Motor V10-07-0005-1 VEMO
Wiper Motor 10-07-0005    VEMO
Wiper Motor 1198200500    JP GROUP
Wiper Motor 1J6 955 711 C SEAT
Wiper Motor 1J6 955 711 C SKODA
Wiper Motor 1J6 955 711 C VW
Wiper Motor 1J6 955 711 F SEAT
Wiper Motor 1J6 955 711 F SKODA
Wiper Motor 1J6 955 711 F VW
Wiper Motor 1J6 955 711 G SEAT
Wiper Motor 1J6 955 711 G SKODA
Wiper Motor 1J6 955 711 G VW
Wiper Motor 1J9 955 711   SEAT
Wiper Motor 1J9 955 711   SKDA
Wiper Motor 1J9 955 711   VW
Wiper Motor 2190510       METZGER
Wiper Motor 404425        SWF
Wiper Motor CWM15326      CASCO
Wiper Motor 404886        VAN HECK
Wiper Motor SWM15326      SANDO
Wiper Motor 64039002      MAGNETI MARELLI
Wiper Motor SWM15326.0    SANDO
Wiper Motor TGL390C       MAGNETI MARELLI
Wiper Motor SWM15326.1    SANDO
Wiper Motor 390201592     BOSCH
Wiper Motor 433506        CARDONE
Wiper Motor 853506        CARDONE
```

Comment: It's B not C I've double checked

Comment: @steeef do you know the exact year/model of the Golf? Want to make sure I'm pointing you in the right direction. If you've got VIN that would be perfect!

Comment: @steeef had a bit more of a dig and the 'B' part is a slightly different Bosch part number: 0 390 201 541  not sure what (if any) difference there is between the two but the Bs do seem to be cheap and plentiful from the usual sources.

Comment: Thank you for all your help but I do not know any more information about the Golf other than the generation.

Comment: @steeef No worries.. as far as I can tell both the "B" and "C" variants are listed for the full timespan of the MkIV so really not sure what the differentiation is. Safe bet is always going to be to swap like for like really.